# chrome extension: export append to file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I built a chrome extension web scraper with a button 1-click button that export to as .csv file. Once the <kbd>export</kbd> button clicked, the data will be exported to csv and that is working well :)

Now, I'm extending my app to be more functional. Once I clicked the <kbd>export</kbd> button again, the scraped file should be appending to the csv list but I am stuck.

Questions: How should I do this or do you know any lib to make this functional?

Thank you for taking your time reading my problem.

Comment: It is not very clear what the problem is. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem simply append file to the last row of the exported csv.

Comment: do you mean like joining the two files into one ? Or what ? How is the CSV created and how the scraped file ? (Maybe posting some code would make things clearer.)

Comment: @ExpertSystem you're right. join the data in the same file, not actually they are two files. just append to the last row.

Comment: And where do you get those files ? Aren't you creating it ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem ofcourse files come from the web. it's actually web scraper. this is already working. what i am asking here is, is there a way i can append more data on the file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45289/discussion-between-mar-cejas-and-expertsystem)